# Listen to websocket on background

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a project using Cordova and the ionic framework. It will be available on iOs and Android.

I want to implement websockets on the project (the server-side is already done), and I basically know how to do that for the writting, but I'd like it to read, 'listen', on the websockets also when the app is not on foreground.

From what i saw in my researchs, I guess I will have to implement background services in both languages (Java and Swift), but if it's possible to avoid that....
The main problem is I don't really know where to start and my researchs didn't lead to a lot of results.

Thanks

EDIT: to be more precise, the part of the app that will use websockets is a chat, and I'd like to continue sending notifications when a message is received, even if the app is not on foreground.

Comment: There are not background services on iOS. You will have to make your app run in the background, but this is only allowed for VOIP, audio, location or accessory apps. If you app does not fall with these categories you can only use a method where by you can execute a task when the app goes into the background. This task is limited in time ( 3 to 10 min. max.). For iOS if the socket for up to date information in your app you might want to look as push notification. These can trigger an update.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a precision to my question : "to be more precise, the part of the app that will use websockets is a chat, and I'd like to continue sending notifications when a message is received, even if the app is not on foreground."

Comment: Well this is not possible. You will need to send Push notification to the app while it is in the background and fetch the message as soon as the app comes back to the foreground.

Comment: Okay, I understand that it's not possible on iOs, then I'm thinking about using push notifications (OneSignal is free, for example and seems nice). But basically how can i do that? I tell my server to send a push notification when a message is received? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, any message received for the user should be send to as a push notification to the users device. You will need to store the message on your server until the user opens their app and fetches all the message that where not received while the app was in the background.

Comment: Then there's something I don't understand, how does apps like facebook do to receive a message notification while the app is not on foreground?

Comment: How do you mean? Push notification are handled by iOS not your app.

Comment: Yeah i know, but that means that the only way to receive a notification for a "new message" is to pass by push notifications?
Because that means knowing the type of device OS and storing every device information on the server, I guess

Comment: Yes, that is how Push notifications work.